# Sorting multi column .csv File Python

Tags: excel, sorting, python-3.x

My Data looks like this:

```
549  648.077  0.01
552  648.141  0.45
554  647.167  0.1
572  648.141  0.3
530  630.213  0.69
560  670.312  0.70
```

there are a few thousand lines in the file

the `1st`row values range from `0-1100`

the `2nd`row values range from `600-700`

the `3rd`row values range from `0-1`
I need to plot the data and therefore need to sort and modify the data:

I need to split the 3rd row values (normal range `0.0-1.0`) into segments `0.0-0.20`, `0.21-0.40`, `0,41-0,60`, `0.61-0.80`,`0.81-1.00`

Next I need to split the segments from the `1st`row (normal range (`0-1100`) into segments like `0-10`, `11-20`,`21-30`and so on up to 1100. 
What I want to do is find all `2nd`row values within a region `0.0-0.20` and `0-10` , `0.0-0.20` and `11-20`,`0.0-0.20` and `21-30`.

When found I want to add them all together and divide the value by the number of appearances to get the mean value: so I want for a region between  `0.0-0.20` and `0-10` one `value`. I'm fairly new to python and I think that this is some kind of approach:

```
import os                                                      
import csv                                                     
dataList = []                                                  
with open("table.csv") as csv_file:                         
data_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect='excel-tab')        
for rows in data_reader:                                       
    if float(rows[2]) <= 0.20:                                 
        if float(rows[0]) <= 10:                               
           print(rows)                                       
        if 10 <float(rows[0])<=20:                            
            print (rows)
```

That should work (without the print of course) to get the values, repeated than for `if 20<float(rows[2])<= 30:` ..... That should bring me the values I want but is there an easy way to set a range going from 0-1100 in 10 units step?

P.S.: I am aware that I gave lots of Info for a relative short question and that's because I don't really know if python is the best way to do this and if my approach is reasonable? Maybe I should go with `panda` but that I just installed. So in case anyone knows an easier (maybe not coding related) way to solve a problem like this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sorting key to put your data in the correct order; then you can cycle through it to group it and get your sums.  `itertools.groupby` is excellent for this type of thing:

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import groupby

data_list = []
with open("table.csv") as csv_file:
    data_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect='excel-tab')
    for row in data_reader:
        # read and convert data
        data_list.append((int(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2])))

def classify(row):
    # returns classification of row based on third value, then first value
    # i.e. [549, 648.077, 0.01] -> (0.0, 540)
    #      [572, 648.141, 0.3]  -> (0.3, 570)
    first, second, third = row
    for level3 in (0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8):
        if third <= level3:
            break
    else:
        level3 = 1.0
    for level1 in range(10, 1100, 10):
        if first <= level1:
            break
    else:
        level1 = 1100
    return level3, level1

data_list.sort(key=classify)

plot_values = []

for key, group in groupby(data_list, classify):
    group = list(group)
    number_of_elements = len(group)
    mean = sum([r[2] for r in group]) / number_of_elements
    plot_values.append((key, mean))

print('\n'.join(['%-10s -> %s' % (k, m) for k, m in plot_values]))
```

When run against the sample data you provided:

```
(0.2, 550) -> 0.01
(0.2, 560) -> 0.1
(0.4, 580) -> 0.3
(0.6, 560) -> 0.45
(0.8, 530) -> 0.69
(0.8, 560) -> 0.7
```

Comment: Thank you very merry much that module is great: I only changed the `mean = sum([r[2] for r in group])` into `mean = sum([r[1] for r in group])` since I want the mean value from the second row data for each segment but it seems I did not mention that cleary. No it looks like it's working exactly the way it's supposed to work